# Should I use QGraphicsView to display an image and some decorated text side by side?

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I want to create a "details" view for books I have downloaded.
With the attached image as an example, imagine the red block to the left is the book's cover page, and metadata related to it is displayed to the right.
With the way I have it done right now:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc

class Details:
    def __init__(self):
        self.location = "/home/user/Desktop/Untitled.png"
        self.title = "Some title"
        self.subtitle = "Sub title"
        self.id = 123124

    def to_html(self):
        return """
<p>
<b>Author =</b> author<br/>
<b>Published Date =</b> 2000-1-1<br/>
<b>Pages =</b> 500<br/>
</p>
"""

class DetailsWidget(qtw.QWidget):
    _title_font = qtg.QFont()
    _title_font.setBold(True)
    _title_font.setPixelSize(24)

    _subtitle_font = qtg.QFont()
    _subtitle_font.setBold(True)
    _subtitle_font.setPixelSize(19)

    _id_font = qtg.QFont()
    _id_font.setBold(True)
    _id_font.setPixelSize(15)

    _redacted_details_font = qtg.QFont()
    _redacted_details_font.setPixelSize(12)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 500)
        self.setWindowFlag(qtc.Qt.WindowType.Dialog, True)

        self.setLayout(qtw.QGridLayout())
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self._details: Details = Details()
        self._thumbnail_image = qtg.QImage(self._details.location)
        self._thumbnail_image = self._thumbnail_image.scaled(
            500,
            500,
            qtc.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio,
            qtc.Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation,
        )
        self._details_rect = qtc.QRect(
            self._get_actual_geometry().left() + self._thumbnail_image.width() + 10,
            self._get_actual_geometry().top(),
            self._get_actual_geometry().width() - self._thumbnail_image.width() - 20,
            self._get_actual_geometry().height(),
        )

        height = 0
        self._title_rects = []
        font_metrics_rect = qtg.QFontMetrics(self._title_font).boundingRect(
            self._details_rect, qtc.Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap, self._details.title, 0
        )
        drawing_rect = qtc.QRect(self._details_rect)
        self._title_rects.append(drawing_rect)
        height += font_metrics_rect.height() + 10
        drawing_rect = qtc.QRect(self._details_rect)
        drawing_rect.moveTop(height)
        self._title_rects.append(drawing_rect)

        font_metrics_rect = qtg.QFontMetrics(self._title_font).boundingRect(
            self._details_rect, qtc.Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap, self._details.subtitle, 0
        )
        drawing_rect = qtc.QRect(self._details_rect)
        height += font_metrics_rect.height() - 3
        drawing_rect.moveTop(height)
        self._title_rects.append(drawing_rect)
        font_metrics_rect = qtg.QFontMetrics(self._title_font).boundingRect(
            self._details_rect,
            qtc.Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap,
            str(self._details.id),
            0,
        )
        self._title_rects.append(drawing_rect)
        height += font_metrics_rect.height() + 10
        self._details_rect.moveTop(height)

        self._redacted_details_text_document = qtg.QTextDocument()
        self._redacted_details_text_document.setHtml(self._details.to_html())
        # First set the width,
        self._redacted_details_text_document.setTextWidth(self._details_rect.width())
        # then get the height of the QTextDocument based on the given width and set
        # that + the titles heights + bottom padding as the total height.
        if (total_height:=height + self._redacted_details_text_document.size().height() + 10) > self.height():
            self.setFixedHeight(total_height)

    def _get_actual_geometry(self) -> qtc.QRect:
        # Probably not needed for normal desktop environments with window
        # managers but I'm an epik i3 user so self.geometry() does not work as
        # intended when full screening the window with $mod + F. Or I'm just
        # retarded and this is not even a problem.
        geometry = self.geometry()
        geometry.setTopLeft(qtc.QPoint(0, 0))
        return geometry

    def paintEvent(self, event: qtg.QPaintEvent) -> None:
        total_height = 0

        painter = qtg.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(qtg.QPainter.RenderHint.TextAntialiasing)

        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self._thumbnail_image)

        painter.save()
        painter.setFont(self._title_font)
        painter.drawText(
            self._title_rects[0], qtc.Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap, self._details.title
        )

        painter.setFont(self._subtitle_font)
        painter.drawText(
            self._title_rects[1], qtc.Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap, self._details.subtitle
        )

        painter.setFont(self._id_font)
        painter.drawText(
            self._title_rects[2],
            qtc.Qt.TextFlag.TextWordWrap,
            str(self._details.id),
        )

        painter.translate(self._details_rect.topLeft())
        painter.setFont(self._redacted_details_font)
        self._redacted_details_text_document.drawContents(painter)
        painter.restore()

app = qtw.QApplication()

widget = DetailsWidget()
widget.show()

app.exec()
```

I can display the text and the image next to each other just fine, but the text is not selectable. Looking around for a way to do so, I stumbled upon `QGraphicsTextItem`. Should I re-do the whole thing in a `QGraphicsView` instead of using the `paintEvent` on a `QWidget`? The reason I'm hesitant to do so is because I  don't know of the cons of using a `QGraphicsView`, maybe it's a lot more resource heavy and not the best for this use case?

[image]

Comment: Use a [QLabel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlabel.html) to display the image, a [QTextBrowser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextbrowser.html) to display the text/html, and [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html) to control the geometry. That should only require a few dozen lines of simple code at most, since Qt is designed to do most of the work for you. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @ekhumoro Can I have different fonts/backgrounds/colors for the text content inside `QTextBrowser`? Like a line with black text and white background and another with red text and green background, etc. for the same block of `QTextBrowser` text.

Comment: Of course you can - QTextBrowser displays rich-text, so you can style the content using html tags and/or css. (To be more specific, you can use the [subset of html/css](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) supported by Qt, which should be more than adequate for your requirements). If you take the approach outlined in my comment above, you can easily achieve want you want without the need for complex calculations. Also: the graphics-view framework is totally unsuited for such a simple task as displaying an image alongside some styled text, so there's no need to consider that.

Answer (score 0):

You're complicating things unnecessarily.

Just use a basic QHBoxLayout and two QLabels, with the one on the left for the image, and the one on the right for the details.

If you want to allow text selection, use `QLabel.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)`.

An even better solution would be to use a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsPixmapItem for the image (using `fitInView()` in the `resizeEvent` to always show it as large as possible) and a QTextEdit for the details, set in read only mode.

Note that your usage of `_get_actual_geometry` is wrong in principle (besides the fact that you're calling 4 times in a row, while you could just use a local variable instead), because when a widget has not been shown yet it **always**  has a default size (100x30 for widgets created with a parent, otherwise 640x480), so not only you'll be getting a wrong geometry, but you're also changing it, since `setTopLeft()` will only move the corner, not translate the rectangle: if you want the basic rectangle of the widget, just use [`rect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop). Obviously, if you properly use layouts as suggested above, this won't be necessary in the first place.

Comment: Can I have different fonts/backgrounds/colors for the text content inside `QLabel` or `QTextEdit`? Like a line with black text and white background and another with red text and green background, etc. for the same block of `QLabel`/`QTextEdit` text.

Comment: @Neat text-based Qt widgets (QLabel and QTextEdit/QTextBrowser) support a [limited HTML subset](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html) that follows the HTML 4 specification. You can use *basic* (in ~2020 terms) HTML formatting with it, so don't expect compliance with modern browser rendering; see the documentation above to see the main differences. Note: QTextEdit makes a difference between the `html` and `plainText` (no parsing) properties, while QLabel "guesses" the contents (aka: if the `setText()` value contains tags). Also, QLabel doesn't support scrolling and has some layout issues.

Comment: I see, I'll go with the `QGraphicsView` with a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and 3 `QGraphicsTextItem`s then.

Comment: @Neat Why?!? From what you've explained, there's really **no** need for that. Do you realize the difficulties involving QGraphicsScene transformations, geometry and text displaying management? Not only the laying out of QGraphicsItems is *not* an easy matter, but QGraphicsTextItem uses the same API as QLabel and QTextEdit (which is QTextDocument), and also involves more complications caused by view/scene/item transformations. I've already said it in my post: *don't complicate things*. You want to show an image at on side, and formatted text on another: just use **two** separated widgets.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but from your usage of `self.geometry()` it seems clear that you don't have enough experience with Qt to do what you described in your last comment: if you had it, either you wouldn't have asked this question, or you wouldn't have considered that option so lightly at all. I sincerely hope that you're not trying to do that because you don't know basic HTML that much, because that would be a terrible choice: properly managing QGraphicsItems geometries (especially text based ones) is **much** harder than studying basic HTML, especially considering modern HighDPI capabilities.